# Trying to insert 2 records in 2 custom objects which AREN'T in a Relationship via Lightning Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller, helper, dml-operations

I am trying to create a record in 2 objects at a time.
Object 1 = Guest_Master__c Guest ; its fields =Guest_First_Name__c, Guest_last_name__c, Guest_email__c, Guest_phone__c.
Object 2 = Hotel_Master__c; its fields = Hotel_Type__c, Hotel_City__c
(others fields mentioned in component dont need to be added in any object)
The requirement is that i need to be able to create 2 records in the above 2 objects and i am getting
below error::

> Error in $A.getCallback() [state is not defined]
>
> Callback failed: apex://GuestHotelCreateRecordClass/ACTION$createGuestRecord
>
> Failing descriptor: {markup://c:GuestHotelCreateRecordComp}

Below are my codes::

**APEX class (SERVER SIDE CONTROLLER)**

```
public with sharing class GuestHotelCreateRecordClass {
```

@AuraEnabled
public static void createGuestRecord(Guest_Master__c Guest){
try{
system.debug('GuestMastCreateRecord '+ Guest);

if(Guest != null){

//DML INSERT operation
insert Guest;

}
} catch (Exception e){
system.debug('Error from APEX class for Guest fields' + e.getMessage());
}
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void createHotelRecord(Hotel_Master__c Hotel){
try{
system.debug('HotelMasterCreateREcord '+Hotel);

if(Hotel!=null){
insert Hotel;
}
}catch (Exception e1){
system.debug('Error from APEX class for HOTEL fields' + e1.getMessage());}
}
}

//after MDR Hotel is primary and guest is secondary

**HELPER**

```
({
```

helperMethodCreateGuest:function(component,event){

//for logs
console.log('In create Guest record function');

//getting the candidate information
var varGuestClient=component.get("v.AttrGuestClient");

//calling APEX function
var action1= component.get("c.createGuestRecord");

//setting params
action1.setParams({
"Guest":varGuestClient});

//setting the callback
action1.setCallback(this,function(response){
var state = response.getState();

//check if result is successful
if(state === "SUCCESS"){

//Reset the UI form when record is successfully submitted in database
// field name to match exact to OBD case sensitive
var newEmptyGuestClientRec =  {'sobjectType': 'Guest_Master__c',
'Guest_First_Name__c':'', 'Guest_Last_Name__c':'',
'Guest_Phone__c':'',
'Guest_Email__c':''};

component.set("v.AttrGuestClient",newEmptyGuestClientRec);
alert('Guest record created successfully');

}else if(state === "ERROR"){

alert('Error1 is calling from server side action');

//error details
var ErrorDetails1= response.getError();
alert('Reson for the error = ' + ErrorDetails1[0].message);}
//function(response) ends here
});
$A.enqueueAction(action1);
},

//Helper 2

helperMethodCreateHotel:function(component,event){

//for logs
console.log('In Create Hotel record function');

//getting hte candidate information
var varHotelClient = component.get("v.AttrHotelClient");

//calling APEX fuction
var action = component.get("c.createHotelRecord");

//setting params'
action.setParams({
"Hotel":varHotelClient});

//setting callback from APEX class
action.setCallback(this,function(response){
var state = response.getState();

//check if result is successful
if(state === "SUCCESS"){

//Reset the UI form when record is successfully submitted in database
var newEmptyHotelClientRec = {'sobjectType': 'Hotel_Master__c',
'Hotel_City__c':'',
'Hotel_Type__c':''};

component.set("v.AttrHotelClient",newEmptyHotelClientRec);
alert('Hotel record created successfully');

}else if(state === "ERROR"){

alert('Error2 is calling from server side action');

//error details
var ErrorDetails2= response.getError();
alert('Reson for the error = ' + ErrorDetails2[0].message);}
//function(response) ends here
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
}})

**CLIENT-SIDE CONTROLLER**

({
//create 1 JS controller for both objects

CreateCompleteRecord:function(component, event, helper) {

if(helper.helperMethodCreateGuest(component,event)){

//getting the candidate information
var varGuestClient=component.get("v.AttrGuestClient");

//validations for guest fields
if($A.util.isEmpty(varGuestClient.Guest_last_name__c) || $A.util.isUndefined(varGuestClient.Guest_last_name__c) ){
alert('Last Name is required');
return;}
if($A.util.isEmpty(varGuestClient.Guest_phone__c) || $A.util.isUndefined(varGuestClient.Guest_phone__c) ){
alert('Phone number is required');
return;}    }

if(helper.helperMethodCreateHotel(component,event)  ){

//getting the candidate information
var varHotelClient=component.get("v.AttrHotelClient");

//validation for hotel fields
if($A.util.isEmpty(varHotelClient.Hotel_Type__c) ||$A.util.isUndefined(varHotelClient.Hotel_Type__c)    ){
alert('Hotel Type is required');
return;}
if($A.util.isEmpty(varHotelClient.Hotel_City__c) || $A.util.isUndefined(varHotelClient.Hotel_City__c)  ){
alert('City is required');
return;}    }

}
})

**COMPONENT**
` <aura:component controller="GuestHotelCreateRecordClass" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name ="AttrGuestClient" type="Guest_Master__c" default="{'sObjectType':'Guest_Master__c'}"/>

<aura:attribute name="AttrHotelClient" type="Hotel_Master__c" default="{'sObjectType':'Hotel_Master__c'}"/>

Guest Entry Form




 First Name : 



 Last Name : 



 Email : 



 Phone : 



 City of Hotel : 



 Preferred Hotel Type (3/4/5 Star) : 


















Create 
   

`

Image of Component code attached

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: i dont know why is my component showing so weird even when i tried to paste the component code

Comment: In the future, use the `{}` button to format code. Do not use the triple-backtick syntax that you'd find in normal Markdown, it does not work here. Instead, code is prefixed by four spaces/1 tab when in a code block, and surrounded by a single backtick if referring to code inline.

Comment: ok will keep in mind. please share feedback on my code